# Write userID to field automatically every time an object is edited

Tags: qgis, sql, update, user-account

Currently every user has to put his/her useriD in a field after every change made to an object in the database. This takes time and can be forgotten easily.

Is there a SQL-Command giving back the computer or user editing the data? How can I implement the field being refreshed everytime someone edits one of the other object attributes?

*QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa*

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about the environment which RDBMS, operatings system and so on.

Comment: This is a trivial capability of most databases, but you need to specify the database product in order for the question to be answered.